# Help on glossaries.sty

Tags: glossaries

My code are as follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[toc,nonumberlist]{glossaries}

\begin{document}

\newglossaryentry{algorithmic}
{
  name=algorithmic trading,
  description={a type of trading based on the use of computer algorithms (`algos') to automatically submit, cancel, and otherwise manage order}
}

  \newglossaryentry{hidden}
{
  name=hidden order,
  description={an order type that displays none or only a portion of the order to other market participants}
}

\glossarystyle{altlist}
\glsaddall
\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

After compilation, I run the commands `makeindex -s filename.ist -o filename.gls filename.glo`

Then again I recompile the files, but the entries are not coming in the output, hope I missed some steps, can anyone suggest?

Also, note that I need the entries to be run in with main entry name, i.e., output should come as:

**algorithmic trading.** a type of trading based on the use of computer algorithms (`algos') to automatically submit, cancel, and otherwise manage order

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not contain `\makeglossaries`. This line is required to write to the auxiliary file (else you will get an error about "No \@istfilename found in filename.aux").

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[toc,nonumberlist]{glossaries}

\newglossaryentry{algorithmic}
{
  name=algorithmic trading,
  description={a type of trading based on the use of computer algorithms (`algos') to automatically submit, cancel, and otherwise manage order}
}

  \newglossaryentry{hidden}
{
  name=hidden order,
  description={an order type that displays none or only a portion of the order to other market participants}
}

\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
Test

\glossarystyle{altlist}
\glsaddall
\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, its working, accidentally I missed it, thanks for your attention, how can I make run in the main words and following text as shown in my example...

Comment: @MadyYuvi I did not exactly understand what you want, but did you try `\glossarystyle{list}` instead of `\glossarystyle{altlist}`?